# Почему у меня line-height на одном пк один, а на другом другой?

Tags: html, css

**Всем привет!**
Недавно произошла забавная ситуация.
Верстал я значит макет и увидел, что почему-то по PP у меня идёт расхождение хотя всё задано верно.
Открываю DevTools и вижу, что высота блока совсем другая.
Пошёл проверять в Firefox и на удивление там всё нормально. -_-
Думаю ладно может быть я сошёл с ума и чтобы окончательно убедиться пошёл проверять в BrowserStack.
И что вы думаете?)
Высота блока там такая же, как и в Firefox у меня на пк.
Я действительно озадачен этой проблемой потому что непонятно из-за чего она произошла.

---

Вот скриншот с моего пк в браузере Edge Win 10 - https://ibb.co/j3bf8Wv
Скриншот с BrowserStack тоже Edge Win 10 - https://ibb.co/z4N1kKs

---

Стили, которые прописаны для текста через `class`:

```
.inner__desc {
  font-family: var(--third-font-family);
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.625; (или 26px)
}
```

Стили, которые наследуются от `html`:

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.15; (перечёркнут, что логично ибо перебивает класс)
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

---

Если немного сюда подключить математику, то можно вычислить следующее `height = line-height * кол-во строк`.
Т.е. у меня высота должна равняться в Edge `130px`, собственно, как и в Firefox, но нет там высота `128px`.
Везде масштаб стоит `100%`, так что это не из-за него.
Подскажите, может быть кто-то знает  из-за чего такая проблема могла возникнуть :)

Comment: а шрифт в вашей ос в Edge какой рендерится?

Comment: @highpassion везде 16px. Самое, что забавное в Chrome 130px у меня, а в опере также 128px. Но все они работают на Blink. Т.е. по идее должно быть одинаково, но нет.

Comment: Выложите на codepen пример.

Comment: это размер шрифта, а в Edge devtools есть вкладка Элементы->Вычисляемые-> Отображаемые шрифты в конце всех свойств

Comment: @SineYlo выложите пример

Comment: @highpassion вот - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-qdjepd?file=index.html
Вроде ничего не забыл, сделал так же, как у меня в редакторе +-
Посмотрел вкладку отображаемые шрифты там написано сетевой ресурс.
Шрифт грузится из папки локально.

Comment: у меня пример в edge и chrome дает 130px, если у вас не так - то проблема ваших настроек браузера

Comment: @highpassion можешь подсказать, как это всё исправить? Фишка в том, что как уже написал выше в Firefox и в Chrome у меня 130px, а в Edge, Yandex и Opera 128px :(
Уже это очень давно и не знаю, как решить

Comment: @SineYlo если есть возможность - я бы удалил браузеры со всеми их настройками (часто диалоговое окно вылезает по поводу настроек при деинсталяции), переустановил бы и посмотрел

Comment: @highpassion хорошо в ближайшее время переустановлю эти браузеры и отпишусь

Comment: А с другим шрифтом проверяли?

Comment: @highpassion в общем намучился я тут с переустановкой всех браузеров. Переустановил проблема не решилась. Попробовал поставить другой шрифт, как подсказал человек выше (ставил Poppins, Montserrat) - всё также 128px. Это провал походу))

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, не помогло

Comment: попробуй создать нового пользователя в Windows, там сразу же в Edge открыть

Comment: @highpassion всё решился вопрос, смог понять из-за чего проблема благодаря новой учётке. В общем оказывается проблема в том, что в параметрах экрана у меня стоял масштаб 125%, что больше рекомендуемого. Почему я так поставил потому что монитор большой и при 100% маленькое всё. Вернул на 100% и теперь везде одинаково :). Спасибо большое. Добавь ответ на этот вопрос я помечу мало ли кому пригодится.

Comment: супер много ответов про масштаб экрана/браузера, я даже отвечал сам на подобный вопрос в прошлом месяце, баллы за это не хочу получать, оформил общий ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит проверить масштабирование не только в браузере, а в самой ОС, что влияет на размер всех элементов на экране.

Comment: Зачем делать ответ общим?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну он балы не захотел получать из его слов)

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте line-height в rem

```
.inner__desc {
  font-family: var(--third-font-family);
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 1.625rem; (или 26px)
}
```